# Mongoid query using 1:M relationship

Tags: mongoid

I have a collection A and collection B

In Model A I have declared - has_many: B

In Model B I have declared - belongs_to: A

So I can query like 'A.B' which returns all Bs associated with A.

How to query to select only those A's where A.B.size is 0

Ex: A.where(some_condition).and(:A.B.size => 0)

Answer (score 0):

A=collection name for A
B = collection name for B

First we will fetch all the unique foreign_keys of A which are inserted in B.

```
data_in_b = B.where(condition).pluck(:a_id)
a_ids = A.all.pluck(:_id) // ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5"]
if data_in_b.count > 0 
    a_fks_in_b = data_in_b.uniq // ["id1", "id5"]
    ids_in_a_without_b = a_ids - a_fks_in_b // ["id2", "id3", "id5"]
end
```